# Does adding TOP 1 to a SELECT statement change performance when there is only one result

Tags: sql-server, performance, select

I have a table with millions of rows and many columns with a unique index on the `ID` column in SQL Server.

I have read the previous threads about using `SELECT TOP 1`. However this is a specific case where selection is made by the index and it is known in advance that there can be only one result (or no result if the record does not exist).

In such a case, is there any performance difference between the two:

```
SELECT TOP 1 A, B, C, D, E, F 
FROM TBL_X 
WHERE ID = 123

SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F 
FROM TBL_X 
WHERE ID = 123
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Inspect the execution plans and see what, if anything, changes. Logically it seems pretty unlikely... top is only going to speed something up if it can return the first result it finds, but if that is the same as without top, then speed should be the same.

Comment: I am interested in the reasoning for any performance differences in order to understand and create a general rule,

Comment: If you have a unique index which takes you directly to the row, there is no way to access it faster. Please don't create a coding standard of adding top 1 to all queries - I suspect that would end up hiding bugs in the end.

Comment: The only general rule I'd recommend is *write a query that clearly expresses the result you're looking for*. Learn to think of performance as something that you set goals for and *measure* and only start looking at varying the simplest, most straightforward version of your code if it isn't meeting your goals. And when you're in that territory, it's the *specifics* of the actual situation that matter, not some global, always true "rule" you can apply.

Comment: Is your index on ID unique or not, if not unique, i would guess Top 1 would make a difference, otherwise sql server is pretty smart to figure it out itself. I know there are some TOP 1 optimizations it sometimes employs which can both improve and mess up the query, but that's usually when you have joins

Answer (score 1):

For my own curiousity I tried this.

In a 10 million row table with no indexes or PK, when I search on a value that I know is unique:

## With TOP 1

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.BigDate WHERE id = xyz (a different number every time)
```

The search part of the query plan behaved as follows:

### No indexes

```
Physical Operation: Table Scan
Actual number of rows for all executions: 1
Actual number of rows read: 297,917
Parallel: True
```

### Unique index on search field and no clustered index

==

```
Physical Operation: Index Seek
Actual number of rows for all executions: 1
Actual number of rows read: 1
Parallel: True
```

## Without TOP 1

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.BigDate WHERE id = xyz (a different number every time)
```

### No indexes

```
Physical Operation: Table Scan
Actual number of rows for all executions: 1
Actual number of rows read: 10,000,000
Parallel: True
```

### Unique index on search field and no clustered index

```
Physical Operation: Index Seek
Actual number of rows for all executions: 1
Actual number of rows read: 1
Parallel: True
```

In summary, for this test case, for a table without indexes, `TOP 1` required less "actual number of rows read", which would likely translate to performance improvements. Although I imagine if the data being looked for is near the end of the data there would be no difference.

An important note is that you should fill your tables up with as many helpful "hints" to the query planner as possible. So if you know a data field is unique, make sure you add a unique constraint or index to it.